# Show that a set has zero measure with respect to two measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I have a measure $\nu$ defined in $(\mathbb{R}^p, \mathcal{B}^p)$ such that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} x'x \,  d\nu(x) < \infty$$
Given $\nu$ with this property, define the measure $\kappa$ as:
$$\kappa(E):= \int_E x'x \, d\nu(x)$$

I want to show that $\nu(E) = 0 $ if, only if, $\kappa (E)=0$.

This sounds very simple and straightforward, but I don't have the resources to prove it.
I tried to find an expression that involves both $\nu(E)$ and $\kappa(E)$, but I couldn't.

Help!

Comment: what is $x'x$ ?

Comment: @psl2Z perhaps $x^Tx$, or $|x|^2$?

Comment: $x'x = x^T x= |x|^2$

Answer (score 1):

I think $\nu$ could be the point measure of the origin (i.e., $\nu(E)=1\iff 0\in E$). That would make $\kappa$ the zero measure.

Comment: Yes, i would agree.